# Performing group by and aggregrate Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I would like to do an average on a subquery with group by, how should I do this in Django without using raw SQL?

See SQL example:

```
SELECT AVG(calories) AS AVG_DAILY_CALORIES
FROM (
SELECT date, SUM(calories)
FROM products_eaten
GROUP BY date ) daily_calories
```

I already have the subquery (QuerySet) with values and annotate. Adding aggregate after this fails.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, post your query made with ORM and the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved using an aggregrate:

```py
.aggegrate(avg_daily_calories=Average('calories')/Count('date', distinct=True))
```